# Not able to use add_field in logstash

Tags: configuration, logstash

I would like to extract the interface word from a text from logstash.

Sample log - 
2013 Aug 28 13:14:49 logFile: Interface Etherface1/9 is down (Transceiver Absent)

I want to extract "Etherface1/9" out of this and add it as a field called interface.

I am having the following conf file for the same

```
input
{
        file
        {
                 type => "syslog"
                 path => [ "/home/vineeth/logstash/mylog.log" ]
                 #path => ["d:/New Folder/sjdc.show.tech/n5k-3a-show-tech.txt"]
                 start_position=>["beginning"]
        }
}
filter {
  grok {
    type => "syslog"
    add_field => [ "port", "Interface %{WORD}" ]
  }
}
output
{
        stdout
        {
                debug => true debug_format => "json"
        }
        elasticsearch
        {
                embedded => true
        }
}
```

But then i am always getting "_grokparsefailure" under tags and none of these new fields are appearing.
Kindly let me know how i can get the required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grok` filter expects that you're trying to match some text. Since you're not passing any possible matches, it triggers the `_grokparsefailure` tag (per [the manual](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.2/filters/grok#tag_on_failure), the tag is added "when there has been no successful match").

You might use a match like this:

```
grok {
    match => ["message", "Interface %{DATA:port} is down"]
}
```

This will still fail if the match text isn't present. Logstash is pretty good at parsing fields with a simple structure, but data embedded in a user-friendly string is sometimes tricky. Usually you'll need to branch based on the message format.

Here's a very simple example, using a [conditional](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.2/configuration#conditionals) with a regex:

```
if [message] =~ /Interface .+ is down/ {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "Interface %{DATA:port} is down"]
    }
}
```